# Remove Column in Daypilot Scheduler (or set start time on the half hour)

Tags: html, visual-studio-2019, daypilot

I have nearly finished a project using daypilot, my only issue is solving the start hour of the day.

My biggest issue is not being able to start on the half hour.

i wanted to do the following in the vb.net code.

```
DayPilotScheduler1.BusinessBeginsHour = 7.5
```

However that wont work as it expects an int.

I tried the following in the markup.

```
BusinessBeginsHour="7.5"
```

but again, needs an integer.

Essentially, all i want to do is remove the initial half hour column from the day. Using CSS i guess it probably would be or with JAVA. I was reading the DOCS however i am not educated enough in the other languages to deliver on this.

Any help appreciated.

Image to show the column of cells i want gone. Essentialy i want my work day to start at 7:30am.

[image: Column to remove in red (Sorry)]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want that first half to not show, you can use: (C# code)

```
DayPilotScheduler1.SetScrollX(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30));
```

I started using DayPilot this Monday so I know little, but if the `BusinessBeginsHour` doesn't accept an `int` and you can't change the "zoom" to minutes, I think there's nothing to do